# how to get merged array list data in GridView Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Here I have two tables

1. Employeedetails
2. Claimprocess

In employeedetails I have 8 columns:

*Company_name, Employeecode, Employee_name,  father_name, mother_name, wife_name, child1_name, and child2_name*.

In Claimprocess table I have 5 columns:

*Company_name, Employeecode, Employee_name, Healthcard_no, and claim_for*.

In Claimprocess I set a dependent dropdown for employeecode. For example, if admin selects a company_name that automatically shows dependent employeecode, then again admin selects an employeecode that automatically shows the employee_name and employee relations name such as father_name, mother_name, wife_name etc...

This is the dependent dropdown code for employee_code by selecting company_name

**claimform.php**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'company_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->all(),'id','companyname'),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select a company ...',
            'onchange' => '
                                $.post( "index.php?r=employeedetails/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                                  $( "select#claimprocess-employee_id" ).html( data );
                                });',
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]); 
?>
```

**employeedetailscontroller.php**

```
public function actionLists($id)
{
    $countEmployeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
            ->where(['company_id' => $id])
            ->count();

    $employeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
            ->where(['company_id' => $id])
            ->all();

    if($countEmployeedetails>0){
        foreach($employeedetails as $employee){
            echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->employeecode."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option>-</option>";
    }

}
```

This is dependent dropdown code for employee_name and relations_name by selecting employeecode

**claimform.php**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'employee_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
            'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Employeedetails::find()-   >all(),'id','employeecode'),
            'language' => 'en',
            'options' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Select a employeecode ...',
            'onchange' => '
                                $.post( "index.php?r=employeedetails/lists2&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                                  $( "select#claimprocess-claim_for" ).html( data );
                                }),
                                $.post( "index.php?r=employeedetails/lists1&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                                  $( "select#claimprocess-employee_name" ).html( data );
                                });',
            ],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'allowClear' => true
            ],
        ]); 
?>
```

**employeedetailscontroller.php**

```
public function actionLists1($id)
{
    $countEmployeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->count();


    $employeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->all();

    if($countEmployeedetails >= 0)
    {
        foreach($employeedetails as $employee)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->name."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option>-</option>";
    }

}

public function actionLists2($id)
{

    $countEmployeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->count();


    $employeedetails = Employeedetails::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->all();

    if($countEmployeedetails >= 0)
    {
        foreach($employeedetails as $employee)
        {
                echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->father_name."</option>";
                echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->mother_name."</option>";
                echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->wife_name."</option>";
                echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->child1_name."</option>";
                echo "<option value='".$employee->id."'>".$employee->child2_name."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "<option>-</option>";
    }
}
```

In claim_for field I have to select relation names of the particular employee, so what I did is combine all relation fields such as father_name, mother_name etc using array_merge and I got a name in form.

**claimform.php**

```
<?php
          $em = ArrayHelper::map(Employeedetails::find()-  >all(),'id','father_name');
         $emp = ArrayHelper::map(Employeedetails::find()->all(),'id','mother_name');
        $emp1 = ArrayHelper::map(Employeedetails::find()->all(),'id','wife_name');
        $emp2 = ArrayHelper::map(Employeedetails::find()->all(),'id','child1_name');
        $emp3 = ArrayHelper::map(Employeedetails::find()->all(),'id','child2_name');

        $print = array_merge($em,$emp,$emp1,$emp2,$emp3);
        // echo "<pre>";print_r($print);exit();echo "</pre>";

        echo $form->field($model, 'claim_for')->dropDownList($print,['option' => '']); 
?>
```

**The problem:**

While selecting relation I am getting all the relations name in the form, but while saving it in gridview I am getting employee_id instead of merge_array id.

So here I used this code to get relation name, but I dont know whether my write code is right or wrong:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'id',
        'company.companyname',
        'employee.employeecode',
        'employee.name',
        'claim_for',
        [
           'attribute' => 'claim_for',
           'format' => 'raw',
           'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $grid) {
                $temp = $model->claim_for;
                $si = Employeedetails::find()->where(['id' => $temp])->one();
                return $si['father_name'];// here how to bring merged array relation name

        },  
        ],
        'healthcard_no',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

I've been searching for two days but am not able to get it. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

> create field in claimprocess table as claim_for and store the getting value from employeedetails in seperate table. thats it, Hope it will you

claimprocesscontroller.php

> 

```
            $commaList = explode('-', $model->claim_for);
            $model->claimer_name = $commaList[1];
```

> 

```
employeedetails.php
```

> 

```
echo "<option value='".$employee->id. '-' .$employee->name. "'>".$employee-RelationName7."</option>";
```